# iOS Swift data parsing on local entity to another scene of storyboard using CoreData

Tags: ios, core-data, swift3

Im currently using Coredata to parse data from 1 scene to another scene I have already save all the necessary data inside the model I created. But I am not really sure on how to fetch the data on local database that I created what i did is something like this

```
if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
        let appDelegate = (UIApplication.shared.delegate) as! AppDelegate
        let context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext

        //get from CoreData
        do {
            let result = try context.fetch(User.fetchRequest())
            users = result as! [User]

        }catch{
            print("error")
        }
    }

func searchAuth()
{
    let user = users

    let auth = user.userAuth //error message shows here

    self.barcodeRetrieve(auth as! String)
}
```

I plan to fetch 1 of the entity(userAuth) within the local model i were created but the system shows me some error message like

Value of type '[User]' has no member 'userAuth'

Comment: `[User]` is an array, and arrays don't have a method called `userAuth`. Maybe you want to get one of the elements from the array?

Comment: users is an [User] is an array. If you want to get first user from users, then `let user = users[0]`

Comment: ya thank you I just found a solution in which previously I fetch the data with a wrong way and that was meant to fetch data on table instead of calling 1 sets of data